# Fill auto-complete input through JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have an auto-complete input, works great ..

When I fill the content through the JS code, it does not make it in the auto-complete, and I need him to do so.

I tried to put the focus on the input, and run keypress event, it does not work ... What can I do?

Code (which fill in the input):

```
function FillInput() {
        document.getElementById("MyInput").value ='xxx';
        $('.SearchCities').keypress();
        $('.SearchCities').focus();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try triggering the `keyup` event instead, as this is what autocomplete listens for. There probably aren't any handlers bound for `keypress`.